# Corda Rpc Ssl Node configuration via build.gradle

Tags: corda

I've successfully configured a node to use Ssl Rpc by extending the rpcSettings of the node.conf in Corda 3.2 Enterprise:

```
rpcSettings {
  address="localhost:10006"
  adminAddress="localhost:10046"

  useSsl=true
  ssl {
    keyStorePath="/myhome/certificates/rpcsslkeystore.jks"
    keyStorePassword="xyz"
  }
}
```

Now I'm trying to add the Ssl options to the node configuration in the build.gradle file:

```
import net.corda.cordform.SslOptions

task deployNodes(type: net.corda.plugins.Cordform, dependsOn: ['jar']) {
  directory "./build/nodes"
  node {
    name "O=PartyA,L=London,C=GB"
    p2pPort 10005
    rpcSettings {
      address("localhost:10006")
      adminAddress("localhost:10046")

      def mySsl = new SslOptions()       
      mySsl.sslKeystore("/myhome/certificates/rpcsslkeystore.jks")
      mySsl.keyStorePassword("xyz")

      useSsl(true)
      ssl(mySsl)
    ...
}}
```

The problem is that the generated node.conf now contains the attribute "sslKeyStore" instead of the expected "keyStorePath" and therefore cannot be loaded by the node:

```
rpcSettings {
  address="localhost:10006"
  adminAddress="localhost:10046"
  ssl {
    keyStorePassword=xyz
    sslKeystore="/myhome/certificates/rpcsslkeystore.jks"
  }
  useSsl=true
}
```

Still, the class net.corda.cordform.SslOptions does not offer a method named keyStorePath.

Does somebody know how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

This solution works for me:

```
task deployNodes(type: net.corda.plugins.Cordform, dependsOn: ['jar']) {
  directory "./build/nodes"
  node {
    name "O=PartyA,L=London,C=GB"
    p2pPort 10005
    rpcSettings {
      address("localhost:10006")
      adminAddress("localhost:10046")
    }
    extraConfig = [
        'rpcSettings.useSsl' : "true",
        'rpcSettings.ssl.keyStorePassword' : "xyz",
        'rpcSettings.ssl.keyStorePath' : "/myhome/certificates/rpcsslkeystore.jks"
    ]
    ...
}
```